# Apply filter on multiple column in data table

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

**Code i am using**

```
 (DataGridViewAllMusic.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = 
 string.Format("Title LIKE '%{0}%' or Artist LIKE '%{1}%' or Album LIKE '%{2}%' or 
 Comments LIKE '%{3}%' ",TextboxSearch.Text, TextboxSearch.Text, TextboxSearch.Text, 
 TextboxSearch.Text);
```

**Working output:**

suppose datagridview showing song information as (SongTitle on left and Artist on right)

**Title** & **Artist**

**A Tender Life**  &       **Three Degrees**

and i type **Life** in TextboxSearch the datagridview will show the song detail since word **Life** is found in DataTable column **Title**

Now if i search **Degree**, again Degree is found in DataTable column **Artist** so the datagridview will show the same result

**Desired filter:**

Now i also want to search the song in a way like the artist and song title together.

such that
**Three Degrees A Tender Life** if i search this in TextboxSearch, the datagridview should also display the same result as displaying when searching the title or artist separately

Comment: One way to achieve that is to separate the keywords in the TextBox by a separator like `, ` and use it to concatenate the filter. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66579074/14171304) for example.

Comment: @dr.null i just converted your vb.net code in c# and it works amazingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A special thanks to @dr.null . I found his vb.net code and used in c#. It works  great!

[Vb.net by dr.null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66576679/how-to-search-multiple-values-in-one-textbox-and-shown-in-datagridview-vb-net/66579074#66579074)

```
 var sb = new StringBuilder();
 var cols = new[] { "Title", "Artist" };
 var words = TextboxSearch.Text.Split(',').Where(x => x.Trim().Length > 0);

 for (var i = 0; i <= cols.Length - 1; i++)
 {
                               
    for (var j = 0; j <= words.Count() - 1; j++)
    {  
         sb.Append($"{cols[i].Trim()} LIKE ' 
         {words.ElementAt(j).Trim()}%'");
         if (j != words.Count() - 1)
            sb.Append(" OR ");
    }
     if (i != cols.Length - 1)
        sb.Append(" OR ");
 }
(DataGridViewAllMusicDark.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = 
sb.ToString();
```