# I want to use multiple % in BindingSource.Filter

Tags: c#, vb.net, filter, bindingsource

I have thousands of data like

uPVC Elbow 2"-D

uPVC Elbow 6"-D

uPVC Elbow 8"-B

uPVC Elbow 10"-B

uPVC Elbow 4"-D

uPVC Elbow 12"-B

uPVC Elbow 5"-B

uPVC Elbow 3"-B

uPVC Elbow 2"-C

uPVC Elbow 4"-B

uPVC Elbow 6"-B

uPVC Elbow 20"-C

All these data are in a single column called - PName

I want the user to filter data by typing in a textbox

he will type (Elb 5) in the textbox and the data (uPVC Elbow 5"-B) will be filtered out

Code Example:  ProductBindingSource.Filter = "PName Like '%" & Str1 & "%" & str2 & "%'"

In here PName is the column name and Str1 = 'Elb' And Str2 = '5'

After execution of the code there is an exception:

System.Data.EvaluateException: 'Error in Like operator: the string pattern '%Elb%5%' is invalid.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66579074/14171304

Comment: I have down-voted this question because you clearly haven't bothered to read the documentation before posting, which explicitly states that wildcards are only permitted at the beginning and end of a string.

Comment: I am sorry. But I read the documentation. I just don't understand what a wildcard string is. I guess StackOverflow is not a place for beginners or those who know less English. Please can you point me out what is my mistake?

Comment: No sir, of course you are welcome! Just tell us the next time what you have tried yourself to solve the problem. Some relevant code, reference to the docs that you don't understand. Welcome again and glad to have you. Good day.

Comment: @dr.null Thank you sir for encouraging me. The link you have provided is a very useful post. But that is not my problem. I have edited my question a bit so that you can understand it better.  I would also like to share my codes with you. But I am not sure where should I post. Here in the comment or at the answer your question button.

Comment: ah _All these data are in a single column called - PName_. This's different. You need to repeat the `Like` for each. Try for example: `ProductBindingSource.Filter = $"PName LIKE '%{Str1}%' AND PName LIKE '%{Str2}%'";` and see how it goes.

Comment: It worked. it worked. thank you very much. You don't know what you have done for me. I  have been looking for a solution to this problem for the past week. Thanks. Is there any way I can review you?

Comment: Very well. Thank you, just come again.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.